# Do financial institutions in the United States have a deadline to send out tax forms?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, legal

Must financial institutions in the United States abide by some deadlines to release tax forms (e.g., Forms 1099) to their customers? Or can they send them whenever they want?

Comment: Yes, most forms must be sent by Jan 31st, Feb 1st or Feb 15th

Comment: @Vality thanks where can one see the deadlines for each form?

Comment: The deadlines are on the last page of the forms themselves. Take a look at https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/f1099div--2017.pdf for an example

Comment: @Vality Thanks, that's great to know, I hadn't noticed! you are welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IRS Publication 1220](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p1220.pdf) has all these deadlines. See Sec. 6.03 Due Dates (page 16). Most 1099s must be mailed by January 31, with some exceptions (including 1099-B, 1099-S, and consolidated statements that brokerages often issue that combine multiple types of 1099s) for February 15.

Comment: You might want to explicitly bring up the "This also applies to statements furnished As part of a consolidated reporting statement." As most brokers issue a consolidated statement for 1099-B, 1099-DIV, 1099-INT, 1099-MISC and 1099-OID. (As applicable)

Comment: @Vality Good suggestion; done.

Comment: Thanks very much of the information! Follow-up question:  [How comes E-Trades plan to release some tax forms later than specified in IRS Publication 1220?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/119960/5656) Maybe it is due consolidated statements but I don't know when a statement is qualified as "consolidated".

Answer (score 1):

[Internal Revenue Service's Inst 1099 General Instructions (i1099gi)](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1099gi.pdf) also has the deadlines for Forms 1096, 1097, 1098, 1099, 3921, 3922, 5498, and W-2G, see the  three pages of tables near the end of the document.