# Why does E-Trade plan to release some tax forms later than specified in IRS Publication 1220?

Tags: united-states, taxes, legal

Why does E-Trade plan to release some tax forms later than specified in [IRS Publication 1220](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/p1220--2019.pdf)?

Example: 1099-INT is planned to be released  on February 15, 2020 according to https://us.etrade.com/app/taxcenter#/taxdoc whereas IRS Publication 1220, from my understanding, indicates that 1099-INT must be released by January 31, 2020.

Screenshot from https://us.etrade.com/app/taxcenter#/taxdoc:

[image]

Screenshot from [IRS Publication 1220](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-prior/p1220--2019.pdf):

[image]

Comment: I suspect E-Trade does not issue many standalone 1099-INTs. Maybe they are all part of consolidated 1099s and they're just simplifying? I suppose you could ask them and point to the IRS regulations.

Comment: @CraigW Thanks, what is the difference between consolidated 1099s and  standalone 1099-INTs? Does "consolidated 1099s" simply mean that all the provided 1099s come concatenated in the same PDF file?

Comment: Not sure what the official definition is but consolidated 1099s have multiple types of 1099s as part of the same document/mailing/PDF. For example, E-Trade might give you a single document that contains the information of a 1099-INT, 1099-DIV, and 1099-B.

Comment: Also possible that E-Trade requested an [extension](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-8809) from the IRS.